# AMD FirePro v7900 - Driver Needed

Tags: drivers, 22.04, amd-graphics, crash

I have Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 installed on an old HP Z220 CMT Workstation (1790, BIOS K51 v01.14 09/27/2012). 32MB ram, 2HDD.   It has a AMD FirePro v7900 graphics card that supports up to four (4) monitors.  I am currently running a radeon driver but I have struggled to find a driver that supports this graphics card and does not cause my desktop client to crash.  Any time I have more than one monitor hooked up, the desktop crashes within about 10 minutes.  Other times I can be up and running for a few days before it crashes.  I noted the lastest crash time and can provide copies of the relevant logs if it would be helpful.  Just let me know which ones and I can provide more color.  The attached code is from /var/log/syslog from right before the time of the crash:

```
    Aug 21 23:24:02 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348322.515928] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000001dd411d last fence id 0x0000000001dd411e on ring 4)
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.027891] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 4 stalled for more than 31272msec
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.027900] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 31248msec
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.027907] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x00000000005bea4d last fence id 0x00000000005bea4f on ring 0)
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.027912] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000001dd411d last fence id 0x0000000001dd411e on ring 4)
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.535901] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 4 stalled for more than 31780msec
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.535917] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x0000000001dd411d last fence id 0x0000000001dd411e on ring 4)
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.535940] radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 0 stalled for more than 31756msec
Aug 21 23:24:03 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.535951] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup (current fence id 0x00000000005bea4d last fence id 0x00000000005bea4f on ring 0)
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638146] BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: ffffad2140675ffc
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638160] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638164] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638167] PGD 100000067 P4D 100000067 PUD 0
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638175] Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP PTI
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638181] CPU: 5 PID: 2137 Comm: gnome-shell Not tainted 6.2.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638186] Hardware name: Hewlett-Packard HP Z220 CMT Workstation/1790, BIOS K51 v01.14 09/27/2012
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638189] RIP: 0010:radeon_ring_backup+0xd6/0x170 [radeon]
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638338] Code: f1 49 89 07 48 85 c0 74 77 41 8d 7d ff 31 d2 48 c1 e7 02 eb 07 49 8b 07 48 83 c2 04 49 8b 74 24 10 8d 4b 01 89 db 48 8d 34 9e <8b> 36 89 34 10 41 23 4c 24 5c 89 cb 48 39 d7 75 da 4c 89 f7 e8 c1
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638343] RSP: 0018:ffffad1d42efbb78 EFLAGS: 00010202
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638347] RAX: ffff9fdb50100000 RBX: 00000000ffffffff RCX: 0000000000000000
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638351] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffffad2140675ffc RDI: 00000000000c8e40
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638354] RBP: ffffad1d42efbba0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638357] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9fdacdf31620
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638360] R13: 0000000000032391 R14: ffff9fdacdf31600 R15: ffffad1d42efbc00
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638363] FS:  00007f01d42985c0(0000) GS:ffff9fe1b5d40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638367] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638371] CR2: ffffad2140675ffc CR3: 0000000119924003 CR4: 00000000001706e0
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638375] Call Trace:
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638378]  <TASK>
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638384]  radeon_gpu_reset+0x11e/0x580 [radeon]
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638468]  ? dma_fence_wait_timeout+0x68/0x140
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638476]  ? dma_resv_wait_timeout+0x70/0xe0
Aug 21 23:24:04 LinuxC-D1 kernel: [348323.638484]  radeon_gem_wait_idle_ioctl+0xd0/0x120 [radeon]
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Note that I believe the driver is the cause of the crashes, but it could be something else.

Comment: Have you tried using the GA kernel stack (ie. changing kernel modules or *driver* that way)?  On some hardware I've found that a very easy fix (*though its hardware specific and I don't know your video graphics card, I note you're using HWE kernel stack from your provided detail though, and on older hardware the older & more stable GA kernel stack can perform better*).